# What is the name of an independent science fiction film with a strongly worded memo mentioned throughout?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a small independent film several years ago and can not remember the name of it. The entire film happened in a small office setting. It turns out that aliens are invading and some of them are in this office. One of the employees kept saying he was going to send a strongly worded memo about something. He was a bit scruffy with shoulder length hair and a mostly laid back attitude.

I believe that the words "strongly worded memo" are in the lyrics of the song during the end credits.

I have tried looking for the end credit song by the lyrics, and that did not help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This sounds like [Drones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drones_(2010_film)) from 2010.

I haven't seen it, but it's set in an office and is about a universal threat.

Plus it has [this](https://youtu.be/UNzj3goygvA) song about a stongly worded memo.

Answer (score 17):

Could this be "[Drones](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1232775/?ref_=nm_flmg_wr_6)"? That was a small independent film from 2010, in which aliens plan to destroy the Earth, and have sent an advance party of scouts. One of these is a women, working in a small office, and the protagonist of the film, Brian, falls in love with her. There was indeed a scruffy, laid-back guy with long hair played by Dave Allen. If I recall correctly, the opening song was called "Strongly Worded Memo".